# Applying Bayes for treating binary soft classification model output as marginal probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

Consider a soft classification model $f: x \to (0,1)$, with $Z = f(X)$.

Now say that the model evaluates in testing data yields, as shown in the figure below, the distributions conditioned on the true value of the label.

[image: Model output]

Does it make sense to interpret these as probabilities and use theory based on naive bayes to give some probability of the output?

That is, for the outputs given in the figure below, does it make sense to interpret these as densities (after scaling) and use Bayes to interpret them? More specifically

$$p(C_k|Z) = \frac{p(C_k)p(Z|C_k)}{p(Z)}$$
And, assuming that the distributions are behaving as in the figure below, then
$$P(C_0|Z) = \frac{P(C_0)P(Z\leq z|C_0)}{P(Z\leq z)},\ z=f(x)$$
can be interpreded as a likelihood that an observation $x$ belongs to the class $C_0$?

See below for more strong textmaths.

### My reasoning and formalization attempt

Consider the random variables $(X,Y)_i$ jointly distributed, with $X_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $Y_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Further, suppose
I have some (already trained) soft classification model $f:x\in\mathcal{X}\to(0,1)$. Let's for now assume that his is just some continuous transformation of a random variable $X$ s.t. $Z = f(X)$.

Now, with observations $\{(x,y)_1,\ldots,(x,y)_k\}$, consider the marginal distributions of
$Z$: $f(Z|x,y=0)$ and $f(Z|x,y=1)$. For notational purposes;

$$p(Z|C_k) = p(Z|x\in C_k),\ \text{with } \{(x,y) \in C_k \Leftrightarrow y = k \}$$

Now, for observations with hidden $y$s, I could use these marginal distributions to give a likelihood for class memberships using Bayes:

$$ P(C_k | Z=f(x)) = \frac{P(C_k)P(Z|C_k)}{P(Z)} $$

#### But why would you want to do this?

It's simply a way of conveying the output of the classifier as some sort of probability. Just giving the output of $f(x)$ might not be as intuitive for non-analysts.

Also, apologies for the abuse of notation! If it's to much of abuse to be clear, please let me know and I'll make it less abusive.

Comment: I can't speak to your particular solution, but the problem you're trying to solve is called "calibration". You can take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_classification#Probability_calibration . You can try your approach, and evaluate it by creating a calibration plot (bin examples with similar predicted probabilities, and and measure the actual frequency of 1's in the bin...). The wikipedia article also gives other standard solutions to the problem of calibration (Platt Scaling, Isotonic Regression...)

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for! I guess I just didn't know what to google, but this is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @MaxS. If you just say that in an answer I'll accept it. Also, for it to answer the original question, you could also add that there are some calibration approaches that are based on bayesian (Bennett 2002 I think it was) that are based on the same idea as proposedin the op.

Comment: its not clear why would you do this rather than directly use a good probabilistic classifier (that is directly optimised to output calibrated probabilities)

Comment: @seanv507 right. I just didn't know about the calibration field. I suspected it was there and now I know :)